# Specific question about RegEx repeats

Tags: regex

I'm not a RegEx expert so I'm using the following borrowed RegEx to validate email addresses:

```
^[\w\.=-]+@[\w\.-]+\.[\w]{2,3}$
```

A user has reported it's rejecting their email address of frank@brownlie.info. It's the "info" that's being rejected as "inf" works. So I did a bit of reading and learnt what the [\w]{2,3} syntax means and yes, that's why info is getting rejected as it's four characters. Changing it to [\w]{2,4} worked.

I like to understand my problems so dwelled upon this fragment. My question is why is the \w inside square brackets? Would not \w{2,4} also work?

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: What language are you using? Different languages have subtle differences in their RegEx implementations, so it would help to know.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `.` inside character class declarations. Inside a character class declaration only the characters \, `]` and `-` have a special meaning (and `-` only if it’s immediately after a character that is not part of a character range and if it’s not immediately before a `]`).

Comment: As an aside, this falls very far short of validating that the address is syntactically valid. For instance, `"james polley"@gmail.com` (yes, with the quotes and all) and `james+polley@gmail.com` are both valid, but wouldn't be allowed by this regex. The relevant RFC section is http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z42 (look for the definition of 'local-part')

Comment: on the other hand, almost no-one actually supports the `"james polley"` format for the local-part. plus-addressing is quite common though, so you should at least add a `+` into that first character class.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html has a ramble and some examples of better regexs for validating email addresses - even a few that are entirely correct, but mostly useless :p I know this is not what you're asking about, but it's still interesting reading :)

Answer (score 4):

The outer character class in `[\w]` in not necessary as `\w` already denotes a character class. Only if you want to combine characters or predefined character classes you would need the character class notation `[…]` like in `[\w\s]` (word characters and whitespace characters) or `[\w-]` (word characters and the hyphen). So `[\w]` is equal to `\w`.

Comment: \w includes \d so [\w\d] example is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You define character sets in square brackets. For example the first square bracketed part means "any alphanumeric character AND dot AND equal sign AND dash". Then you tell the parser with the following "+" that any character in this set should exists at least once.

In the last part since you only use \w and it means "all alphanumeric characters" by itself, you do not need any square brackets. The quantifiers(+, ?, *, {n,m}) affect the previous character OR character set(should be defined with square brackets as I've explained) only. And yes, "\w" is counted as a single character while parsing the RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Whist both would work, it is generally better style / more readable to group as it makes clear exactly what is being repeated.

I would actually make this more explicit as to cut out some common, valid but unlikely cases (note that if you were to allow all *technically* valid email addresses, pretty much anything would go).

```
^[\w\.=-]+@([\w\d-]+\.){1,3}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```